# Unable to get the usernames user id for sessions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function in my library called `getID` but I am unable to get it added in my sessions I am not to sure why I can get my username OK

I have sessions Autoloaded

**How can I get the user id of the user that is logged in and have it set in the sessions.**

```
public function login() {
if($user_query->num_rows() == 1 ) {
$this->getID = $this->user_id;

$data = array(
'islogged' => true,
'user_id' => $this->user_id,
'username' => $this->CI->input->post('username')
);

$this->CI->session->set_userdata($data);
//$this->CI->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->CI->db->dbprefix . "user SET ip = '" . $this->CI->input->ip_address() . "' WHERE user_id = '" . (int)$this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') . "'");
return true;
} else {
return false;
}

}

public function logout() {
  $this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
}

public function isLogged() {

}

public function getID() {
  return $this->CI->db->get_where('user', array('user_id' => $user_id))->row();
}
```

Comment: might be an obvious question but have you loaded the sessions library?

Comment: Yes I have auto loaded it I just need to be able to the the user that is logged on need to be able to have there user id in sessions I did not put all the login information up only the if num rows part on post

Comment: $this->session->userdata('user_id');

Comment: I need it added in sessions I don't need to get it from sessions

Comment: you have added it in the session already using `$data`????????? I don't get what you mean. Are you saying that `$this->user_id` is not set?

Answer (score 0):

Just underneath your num_rows(), you have this;

```
$this->getID = $this->user_id;
```

If (coming from your question intro), your function to get the users ID is called getID, shouldn't that be the other way round?

```
$this->user_id = $this->getID();
```

Edit:

I didn't notice, but Graham is right. You need to pass the variable with the function, although you are also trying to get the user id, using the user id. Try it with the username (I assume these are unique);

```
      public function getID($username)
      {
                $this->db->select('user_id');
                $this->db->where('username', $username);
                $query = $this->db->get('users');
                if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
                {
                          $row = $query->row();
                          return $row->user_id;
                }
                else
                {
                          return false;
                }
      }
```

...

```
'user_id' => $this->getID($this->CI->input->post('username'))
```

Apologise for any syntax errors. I'm replied from my iPhone.

Comment: Your getID function is returning an array. ->row('user_id')

Comment: I tried this return $this->CI->db->get_where('user', array('user_id' => $user_id))->row($user_id); same issue

Comment: You're trying to get the user_id, using the user_id. I will update my answer with the fixed code.

Comment: I not sure if the getID function is correct to get the user user_id. Maybe that's the issue Maybe thats why has array showing up in stead of the user row number

Comment: Would that get the user row id number?

Comment: It returns the username not the user Id and still has Graham Ritchie way has array [user_id] => Array() it should display '1'

Answer (score 0):

```
$getIDdata = $this->getID($this->user_id);

private function getID($userid) {
    return $this->CI->db->get_where('user', array('user_id' => $user_id))->row();
}
```

As your function depends on a userid you have to pass it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my own issues after looking at code and thinking more on the subject I now have got it working all I had to do is add `$this->user_id = $user_query->row('user_id');`
and `$this->username = $user_query->row('username');` below the num rows area. and return it in my other function below the login function.

**All Working Now I can get the user id number now.**

```
public function login() {
$username = $this->CI->input->post('username');
$password = $this->CI->input->post('password');

$this->CI->db->select('user_id');
$this->CI->db->from('user');
$this->CI->db->where('username', $username);
$this->CI->db->where('password',  hash('sha512', $password));
$this->CI->db->where('status', "1");
$user_query = $this->CI->db->get();

if($user_query->num_rows) {
$this->user_id = $user_query->row('user_id');
$this->username = $user_query->row('username');

$data = array(
'user_id' => $this->user_id
);
$this->CI->session->set_userdata($data);

return true;
} else {
return false;
}

public function getId() {
return $this->user_id;
}

public function getUserName() {
return $this->username;
}
```

Comment: The second parameter on your db->select() function is invalid. The second parameter is optional, and is boolean (only true or false). It defaults to true.  If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.